# laravel Eloquent one to many two relationship. OpenCart table style

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to implement *information* and *information_description* tables in laravel Eloquent Model ? Some how it need to set language, because a title should be a one record.

```
$information = App\Information::find(1);
$information->title
```

[tables structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqRwF.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can review how to do this, and plenty more, by reading the [documents by Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many). They are a great help and this particular question has an example and everything. Having said that, I'll help with getting you started.

- Define a relationship in either model, `information` or `information_description`, or both. For brevity, I'll use `information` only.
- Pass the `foreign_key` and `local_key` in the `hasMany()` relationship since it differs from Laravel's default behavior.

So we have a model that now looks like:

```
class Information extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the descriptions for the Information model.
     * Note the 2nd and 3rd arguments in the method
     * which define foreign_key and local_key.
     */
    public function description()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\InformationDescription', 'information_id', 'information_id');
    }
}
```

Now that you have the relationship defined, you can perform your query.

```
// Get the description for the information
$information = App\Information::find(1)->description;

// Iterate over the results
foreach ($information as $description) {
    $description->title;
}
```

The table naming convention used is a little odd, but if I understand it correctly, this will work. Hope it helps.